# How to obtain m4v metadata using iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is there a way to access the metadata (such as width and height of the video) via iOS SDK for m4v inside the resource bundle? I would like to use this info to center the video around the screen bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a mac this would be easy, because you can utilise the spotlight metadata, but on iOS it's slightly more complicated. A couple of suggestions:

The easiest way to do this is just to load your movie into an `MPMoviePlayerController` and check the `naturalSize` property. There are a number of other properties including `playableDuration`. The downside to this is you have to load the movie into an MPMoviePlayerController, which may be fine for you if you're going to play the file straight away.

The harder but more efficient way is to use the open source [libmediainfo library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/files/binary/libmediainfo0/), but it's obviously more complex to integrate than using an MPMoviePlayerController 'out of the box'.

Comment: Have to wait for the MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification to query naturalSize, thanks for the pointer.